# How to add Dynamics 365 extension to toolbar in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

I want to develop extension for Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations. For that, I need Dynamics 365 extension to Visual Studio 2019 toolbar. But, I am unable to do that. I was going through the following docs :
https://www.alphabold.com/guide-to-install-microsoft-dynamics-365-developer-toolkit-extension-into-visual-studio-2017/. But, it is not showing the dynamics 365 developer toolkit to my visual studio. The following message is showing :
[image: VSIXInstaller]

I want following extension should be added to my Visual Studio that is mentioned with red circle.
[image: D365ExtensionVS2019]

Comment: Could you clarify if you want to install the Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations extension (which the question text and the screenshot indicate) or the Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement (CRM) extension (which the linked blog article is about)? Also note that for Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations, the Community edition of Visual Studio 2017 is not supported. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-tools/developer-tools-vs2017 for further information.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are aiming for is under the Extensions Menu in VS2019.
Extentions --> Dynamics 365
[image]